# Any library for visualizing module dependencies in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, dependencies, visualization, dependency-management

As part of a major refactoring of my Node.js app (going DDD), I'm looking for a library that through inspecting code is able to visualize module dependencies (by means of 'requiring' them) between different node-modules.

Visualizing in Table-format is fine, I don't  need fancy graphs.

Any Node libraries out there?

Comment: https://github.com/hughsk/colony ?

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Sweet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know if this exists, but I found the following by quick [search](http://toolbox.no.de/search?q=require):

- http://toolbox.no.de/packages/subdeps
- http://toolbox.no.de/packages/fast-detective

Maybe subdeps is not exactly what you want right now, but I think you could use these projects to make that project yourself?

Answer (score 4):

If you may accept also some *fancy graphs*: http://hughsk.github.com/colony/

Comment: It should be noted that Colony does not support ES5 `import` nor ES6 syntax, so using arrow functions for example will totally break the parser.

Answer (score 1):

See also https://github.com/pahen/madge

> Create graphs from your CommonJS, AMD or ES6 module dependencies. Could also be useful for finding circular dependencies in your code. Tested on Node.js and RequireJS projects. Dependencies are calculated using static code analysis.

Answer (score 0):

I just published my [node-dependency-visualizer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-dependency-visualizer), which is a small module, that creates a digraph from your node dependencies. Paired with graphviz/dot you can create a dependency graph as svg (or other image format) which you can include with your documentation, embed in your Readme.md, ...

However, it does not check, whether the dependencies are actually needed in code - not sure, whether the OP meant that with "requiring". Of course this question is old, but this tool might be helpful for others, too.

Sample image (Angluar cli):

[image: Sample]